# Android HTML Form - MAILTO Error

Tags: android, html, forms

So I've been working on adding a basic table with a form to an Android app, and so far everything has been working fine except on submission.  When I hit submit, I get an error and no app opens to send the email.  This worked fine on Windows 10 and opened the mail client, so I'm wondering how to fix it.  Here is my table/form code (Sorry for the length):

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="lightgrey" bordercolor="black" width="75">

    <tbody>
        <form action="php-form-processor.php" method="post">

    <tr>

        <td style="color:black; font-family: Comic sans MS">
            <u>Name:</u>
        </td>

        <td>
            <textarea rows="1" cols="33" name="Name" style="color: black; background-color: lightgrey; border-color:black; text-align: left; font-  

            family: Comic sans MS;">Enter your name</textarea>
        </td>

    </tr>

    <tr>

        <td style="color:black; font-family: Comic sans MS">
            <u>Date:</u>
        </td>

        <td>
            <textarea rows="1" cols="33" name="Date" style="color: black; background-color: lightgrey; border-color: black; text-align: left; font- 

            family: Comic sans MS;">Enter the date</textarea>
        </td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
                    <td style="color:black; font-family: Comic sans MS">
            <u>Exercise:</u>
        </td>

        <td>
            <textarea rows="4" cols="38" name="Exercise" style="color: black; background-color: lightgrey; border-color: black; text-align: left;   

            font-family: Comic sans MS;">Enter exercise and time spent on each</textarea>
        </td>

    </tr>

    <tr>

        <td style="color:black; font-family: Comic sans MS">
            <u>Breakfast:</u>
        </td>

        <td>
            <textarea rows="4" cols="38" name="Breakfast" style="color: black; background-color: lightgrey; border-color: black; text-align: left;  

            font-family: Comic sans MS;">Enter your breakfast meal</textarea>
        </td>

    </tr>

    <tr>

        <td style="color:black; font-family: Comic sans MS">
            <u>Lunch:</u>
        </td>

        <td>
            <textarea rows="4" cols="38" name="Lunch" style="color: black; background-color: lightgrey; border-color: black; text-align: left;  

            font-family: Comic sans MS;">Enter your lunch meal</textarea>
        </td>

    </tr>

    <tr>

        <td style="color:black; font-family: Comic sans MS">
        <u>Dinner:</u>
        </td>

        <td>
            <textarea rows="4" cols="38" name="Dinner" style="color: black; background-color: lightgrey; border-color: black; text-align: left;     

            font-family: Comic sans MS;">Enter your dinner meal</textarea>
        </td>

    </tr>

    <tr>

        <td style="color:black; font-family: Comic sans MS">
            <u>Snacks:</u>
        </td>

        <td>
            <textarea rows="4" cols="38" name="Snacks" style="color: black; background-color: lightgrey; border-color: black; text-align: left;     

            font-family: Comic sans MS;">Enter any snacks</textarea>
        </td>

    </tr>

    <tr>

        <td style="text-align:center" colspan="2">

            <input type="submit" style="font-family:Comic sans MS;font-weight:600" value="Submit Form">
        </td>

    </tr>
        </form>

    </tbody>

</table>
```

So what do you guys think?

**UPDATE**

I've since discovered that the error comes up when I set method="post", and when I set method="GET", nothing happens at all.  Hopefully this will help to identify and fix the problem.

**ERROR MESSAGE**
[Here is a pic of the error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcWzS.png)

This picture is with method attribute set to "post" and enctype set to "text/plain".

Comment: What kind of error? Please give us more details.

Comment: Please check photo for more about error message.